# Not draggable element inside Draggable one went wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I've a problem that need you to help me to solve it. I've two list like this.

```
<div id="1" class="item-list draggable">
   <div class="item drag-drop-able">itemA</div>
   <div class="item drag-drop-able">itemB</div>
   <div class="add-button drag-drop-disable">Add Item</div>
</div>

<div id="2" class="item-list draggable">
   <div class="item drag-drop-able">itemC</div>
   <div class="add-button drag-drop-disable">Add Item</div>
</div>
```

The issue here is when I drag `itemC` to `item-list` `id=1` (but do not drop), then move it back to `item-list` `id=2`: it's possible to drag the `itemC` below the `button` `Add item`. it's weird behavior, I guess that is because the `item-list` is `draggable`, so when we drag element quickly, it may allow to drag below the `drag-drop-disable` element. I'm using the sortable of jQuery library.

The DOM is look like:

```
<div id="1" class="item-list draggable">
   <div class="item drag-drop-able">itemA</div>
   <div class="item drag-drop-able">itemB</div>
   <div class="add-button drag-drop-disable">Add Item</div>
</div>

<div id="2" class="item-list draggable">
   <div class="add-button drag-drop-disable">Add Item</div>
   <div class="item drag-drop-able">itemC</div> <!-- incorrect -->
</div>
```

My current solution is put the button outside the `item-list`, it worked but I wonder if we could have any solution that no need to modify the DOM structure?

Comment: It's better to put 'Add Item' button outside draggable div.
But if you want your 'Add Item' button inside your div only then you can fix the position of the button to the bottom of the div using CSS.

Comment: yes, that's my solution, but my TL thing there must be better if do not modify the DOM structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: 
 I found myself solution for this case without move the button out of its wrapper: Add a empty element before

The code will look like:

```
<div id="1" class="item-list draggable">
    <div class="item drag-drop-able">itemA</div>
    <div class="item drag-drop-able">itemB</div>
    <div class="item-divider"></div> <!--magic is here-->
    <div class="add-button drag-drop-disable">Add Item</div>
</div>
```

In my opinion, the empty div will correct the drop event: avoid dropping after the `drag-drop-disable` element.